# Create a template with ref class that inherits from the same ref class

Tags: class, templates, c++-cli

I want to do something like this:

```
template <class SoType> 
public ref class SoTile : SoType
```

As my class is ref and I inherit from SoType, it may be ref

```
template <ref class SoType> 
public ref class SoTile : SoType
```

But when I try to compile it gives me this error:

```
Error   1   error C3816: 'class SoType' was previously declared or defined with a different managed modifier    d:\oceanprojects\lidarinfo\oivlodenode\SoTile.h 7   1   OivLodeNode
```

Some help? Maybe I'm not understanding something...

Comment: You cannot magically transform a native C++ class like SoType into a managed class.  Nor can a native C++ class be the base type of a managed class.  You'll need to think this through a bit, focus on encapsulation to solve this problem.

Comment: `SoType` is a managed class. Actually it must be from .NET (.NET `SoBufferedShape` or .NET `SoPointSet`, from open inventor.)